# Replace the prompt with the buffer name in erc buffers

Tags: emacs, elisp, hook, prompt, irc

How can I replace the `ERC>` prompt in every `erc` buffer so that it shows the name of the buffer instead?

For example if I'm in the `#emacs` channel, I have this:

```
   *** arall (~arall@128.205.23.161) has joined channel #emacs  [22:40]   
   ERC>
```

While I'd like to have this:

```
   *** arall (~arall@128.205.23.161) has joined channel #emacs  [22:40]
    #emacs>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set variable `erc-prompt` to function that will return the current channel's name, something like:

```
(setq erc-prompt  (lambda () (concat (buffer-name) "> ")))
```